# Set theory: how to interpret multiple quantifiers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, set-theory, quantifiers

How does one interpret this ZFC Union axiom? I can't quite understand what is meant after "There exists some elements y for all elements z"? I'm also wondering if the x is a typo.

> $\exists y \forall z(\exists w(z\in w \space \land w \in x)\implies z\in y)$

Comment: No, it is not a typo. The statement says that (for every set $x$ whose elements are sets) there is a set (namely, $y$) that contains the union of the sets in $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $x$ is not a typo, but there should be a $\forall x$ in front of the whole thing:

$$\forall x\,\exists y\,\forall z\,\big(\exists w\,(z\in w\land w\in x)\to z\in y\big)\;.\tag{1}$$

Given a set $x$, the expression asserts the existence of a set $y$ with the following property: for any object $z$, if $z\in w$ for some member $w$ of $x$, then $z\in y$. That is, $y$ contains as an element each object that is an element of some member of $x$.

We want $\bigcup x$ to be $\bigcup\{w:w\in x\}$, meaning that $z\in\bigcup x$ if and only if there is some $w\in x$ with $z\in w$. $(1)$ says that there is a set $y$ that contains everything that we want to have in $\bigcup x$. This $y$ may, however, contain other things as well, since $(1)$ has only a one-way implication ($\to$, not $\leftrightarrow$). However, once we have this $y$, we can use the [axiom schema of comprehension (or separation)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification) to cut it down to exactly $\bigcup x$:

$$\bigcup x=\{z\in y:\exists w\in x\,(z\in w)\}\;.$$

Comment: The statement "given a set x, the statement asserts the existence of a set y" insinuates that y is not a subset of x, right? Sorry, I'm new to discrete math and starting off with MIT OCW is quite a big leap.

Comment: @YinghaoWang: It actually is possible for $\bigcup x$ to be a subset of $x$; this happens if $x=\varnothing$. And since the $y$ guaranteed by $(1)$ could in fact be equal to $\bigcup x$ and not just some superset of $\bigcup x$, it’s possible for $y$ to be a subset of $x$. All that is said about the relationship of $y$ to $x$ is if something is an element of an element of $x$, then that thing is an element of $y$.

Comment: If the expressions were to be represented as a venn diagram, which sets would contain which (in an average case).

Comment: @YinghaoWang: The axiom says that there is a set $y$ such that $\bigcup x\subseteq y$.

Answer (score -1):

The reading is "There exists a $y$ such that, for all $z$, the following statement is true: 'If there is a $w$ such that $z$ is in $w$ *and* $w$ is in $x$, then $z$ is in $y$'".

I think that there is a missing $\forall x$ before the entire statement. If you include that, then you're saying that for any set $x$, there is a set $y$ that is the union of the sets that are elements of $x$. The breakdown is that you consider all possible $z$, and then you check - is it true that there's a $w$ such that $z$ is in $w$ and $w$ is in $x$? In other words, is it true that $z$ is an element of at least one set that is an element of $x$? If so, then $z$ is in the set $y$.

Comment: I'm curious why this answer got down voted.

Comment: @YinghaoWang: I’m a little curious myself. The answer isn’t quite correct, because the expression does *not* say that $y$ is the union of the sets that are elements of $x$: it says that $y$ is a superset of that union. However, the answer *is* on the right track, and downvoting it without explaining what’s wrong is unhelpful, to say the least.

Comment: Thanks both for those comments, and thanks @BrianM.Scott for pointing out that issue with my answer.